# How Can Identify Table in Mysql Union All

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I Have Query As the following

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    (
        SELECT * FROM comments 
        WHERE user_id = '66' AND product_id = '3' 
        AND status = 1 
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (
        SELECT * FROM comments_reply 
        WHERE user_id = '66' AND product_id = '3'
        AND status = 1 ) 
    ) results 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Which Gets Data from two tabel and shows it in order to datetime.now frontside i am showing this data. but now i wants to know that which data is came from which table.

because I am calling a modal to show a comment in modal by this

```
<span class="showcomment text-danger"
     data-cid = <?=$row[0]?>>view Comment</span>
```

But `$row[0]` Gives me an id But How can i identify that this id is came from which Table ?

Comment: question formatting is horrible, but the question itself is legit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rewrite your query as with `tablename` that you want

```
SELECT 'comments' as table_name, col1, col2,... coln FROM comments c
WHERE user_id = '66' AND product_id = '3' 
AND status = 1  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'comments_reply' as table_name, col1, col2,... coln FROM comments_reply cr
WHERE user_id = '66' AND product_id = '3'
ORDER BY col DESC
```

And, i suspect if you have  `user_id`, `product_id` has numeric type then you should use only values without single quote.

```
where user_id = 66 AND product_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to each of your two tables and populate it with a custom string. For example, the first sub query would start like the following with the new column “table_name”... select *, ‘comments’ table_name from comments...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    (
        SELECT "comments" as tablename,* FROM comments 
        WHERE user_id = '66' AND product_id = '3' 
        AND status = 1 
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (
        SELECT "comments_reply" as tablename,* FROM comments_reply 
        WHERE user_id = '66' AND product_id = '3'
        AND status = 1 ) 
    ) results 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```